# Getting function names and their arguments from evaluated JS with Rhino

Tags: java, javascript, function, rhino

I'm using [Rhino](https://www.mozilla.org/rhino/). and after doing

```
Context cx = Context.enter();
Scriptable scope = cx.initStandardObjects();
cx.evaluateString(scope, "function f(x,y){ return x+y}", "<cmd>", 1, null);
```

I'd like to know that there's a function with the name `f` and two parameters `x` and `y`
but could not find any methods that can help me with that.

Comment: looks like I need to use the Parser class from Rhino. It implements everything I need.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108447/get-variables-from-javascript-expression-rhino

Answer (score 0):

Try to use next code.

```
package com.qarea.rhinotest;

import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable;

public class RhinoTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Context cx = Context.enter();
        Scriptable scope = cx.initStandardObjects();
        cx.evaluateString(scope, "function f(x,y){ return x+y}", "<cmd>", 1, null);
        try {
            String result = (String) cx.evaluateString(scope, "f.toString()", "<cmd>", 1, null);
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
//  Maven dependency
//    <dependency>
//      <groupId>org.mozilla</groupId>
//      <artifactId>rhino</artifactId>
//      <version>1.7R4</version>
//    </dependency>
```

The output is:

```
function f(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}
```